# UIVisualEffectView not working in iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9.1

I've been consistently getting a grey background on my UIVisualEffectViews with blur enabled in iOS 9.1

If I enable vibrancy the view will just get a transparent background instead. This can be reproduced both creating the views in code and in storyboard.

I'm wondering if anyone else is experiencing this issue? Same code works in iOS 9.0 and 8.x. This only happens in iPhone 6, but it works on iPhone 6 Plus and other devices.

May be related to [UIVisualEffectView not working on iPhone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877674/uivisualeffectview-not-working-on-iphone-6) - Only difference is my code works on iOS 9.0-

Comment: I have tried to add `UIVisualEffectView` in storyboard and it's working fine on iPhone6.

Comment: show snippet, whichever you tried programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. My fault.

For anyone facing the same issue, the problem is that I had the option **"Reduce Transparency"** switched ON in my accessibility preferences *(Under General->Accessibility->Increase Contrast)*.

This was completely disabling the blur effect and thus making it grey.

Answer (score 0):

you just  need to change Effect from regular to Light

on iOS 10.0 it will work fine but in iOS 9.0 instead of this pice of code ()

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleRegular];
```

use this(working fine with iOS 9.0):

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle: UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
```